# Angular: How to disable the browser default "Leave site" popup and use custom dialogue box in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

I am working on an angular application where I need to hide the default browser "Leave site" popup and use my own custom dialogue box for it. But I am not able to stop the default one. Pls do help.

I tried this window.onbeforeunload = () => null; but still it didnt work.

Comment: it is related to angular 1.x or angular 2+

Comment: tldr: **not possible** duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68189476/how-to-pop-out-custom-modal-when-leaving-or-refreshing-the-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68189476/how-to-pop-out-custom-modal-when-leaving-or-refreshing-the-page)

Comment: @PrashantSingh I am doing it with Angular 16